# gracefully detect a User's inability to support a SHA256 SSL Connection from ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ssl, configuration, iis-6

Both [Microsoft](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2013/11/12/sha1-deprecation-policy.aspx) and [Google](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) have announced the end of SHA1.

In light of this, we are moving to SHA256 for our SSL cert.  Since SHA256 [is not supported before XP SP3](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2010/09/30/sha2-and-windows.aspx), and [about 17% of user use XP](http://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0) (at least some of them will not be using SP3) there will be users who cannot connect to our https pages.

What I would like to do is to have my site recognize that they cannot connect via SSL, and send them to a support page explaining why they cannot connect and telling them how to correct it.

Our website runs ASP.NET on IIS 6.

It seems to me that there should be a Web.Config setting or an IIS setting that will do this.  Does anyone know of any such setting?  [Chris Hutchinson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381708/chris-hutchinson) answer to [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284433/detecting-ssl-browser-support?rq=1) seems to indicate such a setting exists.

Comment: One thought was a custom error page for the error returned by a failed SSL/TLS connection, but I can't seem to find if the server returns an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer for a possible workaround.

Considering that Internet Explorer on Windows XP also has another known SSL/TLS limitation, the fact that it doesn't support Server Name Indication (SNI), you might be able to serve distinguish clients based on whether they use the server name extension in their initial Client Hello message.

You'd need to upgrade to IIS 8 for SNI support (and I must admit I don't know how to configure it for a default site with a different certificate when no server name extension is used), but such detection should at least be feasible from the the protocol point of view. You'd still need a separate SHA-1 certificate for that fallback website.

In this case, any connection coming from IE on XP would go to that fallback site (even with SP3 unfortunately).

Firefox on such an XP machine should be able to handle SHA-256, as its implementation is completely separate from the XP stack.

Chrome could be a problem, since it will use the server name extension, but it also relies on XP's certificate management to verify the CA certificates. I haven't tried, but I'd expect possible problems there.

These are certainly not ideal solutions, but you may find some of these compromises acceptable depending on your requirements.

---

All the above assumes that the user's entry point to your site uses `https://`.

If your users access your site via an `http://` page first, you could make that page make an AJAX request to your `https://` site to check whether it can connect at all, and display an error message if it can't. This is certainly easier and more generic (and wouldn't even require an IIS upgrade). You might not be able to know exactly why that AJAX request fails to connect to your  `https://` site (there are other failure reasons than lack of SHA-256 support), but an explanatory message saying this is one of the most likely causes would certainly help.

Comment: While we want to upgrade the server, right not we are not able to upgrade IIS to anything else.  While the AJAXS Request sounds workable, I suspect that users have bookmarked/created a shortcut to the SSL pages directly, meaning I won't have an opportunity to check.  One of the purposes of the page would be to say "you can try Firefox to connect."

Comment: If an IIS upgrade is not possible, you might be able to put another server in front of it (e.g. Apache, Nginx, ... although I haven't looked into the necessary configuration for that particular use case).

Comment: Because I work for a State government office, our activities are severely constrained by policy and funding.  We could get a new server, but our budget doesn't have room for that expense right now (we can't buy one, we have to rent one from the centralized IT.  The state is a Microsoft shop.)